# split and count the value in column of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with one of the column has comma separated values

```
a = data.frame("A" = c("a,d,w,e", "e,e", "d", "df,w,w,w"), "B" =c(1,2,3,4))
a
#        A B
#  a,d,w,e 1
#      e,e 2
#        d 3
# df,w,w,w 4
```

I want to split the column values by comma and count them at value and put that in another new column

so it would be like

```
      A B   Count
  a,d,w,e 1 4
      e,e 2 2
        d 3 1
 df,w,w,w 4 4
```

I would have provided what I have tried but I am totally clueless for this one. R is so powerful that its confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try:

```
a$res <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(a$A), ","), length)

         A B res
1  a,d,w,e 1   4
2      e,e 2   2
3        d 3   1
4 df,w,w,w 4   4
```

Or written in a simplified way (proposed by @markus):

```
a$res <- lengths(strsplit(as.character(a$A), ","))
```

Here it splits the "A" column by `,` and then assess the resulting length.

Or something like @d.b did but with `stringr`:

```
res <- str_count(as.character(a$A), ",") + 1

         A B res
1  a,d,w,e 1   4
2      e,e 2   2
3        d 3   1
4 df,w,w,w 4   4
```

In this case, it counts the number of commas and adds a + 1.

Or the same logic with base:

```
a$res <- lengths(regmatches(as.character(a$A), gregexpr(",", as.character(a$A)))) + 1
```

Comment: Your first option could also be written as `lengths(strsplit(as.character(a$A), ","))`

Comment: @markus that is a nice possibility, I added it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for something like:

```
a$Count <- sapply(1:nrow(a), 
                  function(x) length(unlist(strsplit(as.character(a[x, "A"]), split = ","))))
```

Output:

```
         A B Count
1  a,d,w,e 1     4
2      e,e 2     2
3        d 3     1
4 df,w,w,w 4     4
```

Comment: yes. exactly. thanks

Comment: You're welcome! See the other solution here, it's more concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(a$A, function(x) 1 + sum(gregexpr(",", x)[[1]] > 0))
#[1] 4 2 1 4
```